# How to Convert my Threshold Image to RGB colour in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
# Import the necessary packages
import cv2
import numpy as np


def back_rm(filename):
    # Load the image
    img = cv2.imread(filename)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Make a copy of the grayscale image
    bg = gr.copy()

    # Apply morphological transformations
    for i in range(5):
        kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,
                                            (2 * i + 1, 2 * i + 1))
        bg = cv2.morphologyEx(bg, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2)
        bg = cv2.morphologyEx(bg, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2)

    # Subtract the grayscale image from its processed copy
    dif = cv2.subtract(bg, gr)

    # Apply thresholding
    bw = cv2.threshold(dif, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    dark = cv2.threshold(bg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Extract pixels in the dark region
    darkpix = gr[np.where(dark > 0)]

    # Threshold the dark region to get the darker pixels inside it
    darkpix = cv2.threshold(darkpix, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Paste the extracted darker pixels in the watermark region
    bw[np.where(dark > 0)] = darkpix.T
    
    #Converting BGR  to RGB
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(bw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


    cv2.imwrite('rgb_image.jpg', rgb_image)


back_rm('example2.jpg')
```

This code basically what it does is removes the watermark from an image. but i want my final output image in RGB instead of black. for example should save the final image 'rgb_image.jpg' in RGB after removing the water mark from the image. but according to the code written it still saves the image in black and white even though i have converted it to RGB. an somon help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0PQa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksGmU.png)

Comment: You're saving `bw` which is a binary map. Converting to RGB will not help. What you want is to save the input image after *coloring in white* the pixels not kept in this binary map  (something like `img[bw == 0] = [255, 255, 255]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving `bw` which is a binary mask - i.e an image full of either 0 or 255.

Converting this image to RGB with `cv2.cvtColor(bw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` will only create black and white values on 3 channels.

Instead, you should use this `bw` mask to fetch the pixel values (RGB) you want to keep from the input image.

Here is a slightly simplified example:

The input image

```py
img = cv2.imread(filename)
```

[image]

Create the mask you want, to target pixels of interest and remove the watermark

```py
# Convert the image to grayscale
gr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Make a copy of the grayscale image
bg = gr.copy()

# Apply morphological transformations
for i in range(5):
    kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,
                                        (2 * i + 1, 2 * i + 1))
    bg = cv2.morphologyEx(bg, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2)
    bg = cv2.morphologyEx(bg, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2)

# Subtract the grayscale image from its processed copy
dif = cv2.subtract(bg, gr)

# Apply thresholding
bw = cv2.threshold(dif, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
dark = cv2.threshold(bg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

final_mask = 255 - bw + dark  # Here is the simplification - for visualization purposes
```

[image]

Only keep the input image RGB values for the pixels inside the mask - otherwise change it to white

```py
#Converting BGR  to RGB
img[final_mask == 0] = [255, 255, 255]
```

[image]